# Right corner item text css

Tags: css

I have two item like that

```
<span active="0">One</span>
<span active="1">Two</span>
```

I want to add a char on active value is "1" span and i want to hide the char of active value is "0" span.

Comment: Which `char`? Can you please make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

```
span[active="0"] { /* write your css */ }
span[active="1"] { /* write your css */ }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually want, but here is something similar:

```
<a onclick="myFunction1()"><span id="one">One</span></a>
<a onclick="myFunction2()"><span id="two">Two</span></a>

<script>
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "World";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't know what he wants, how can you answer the question?

Comment: It calls "guessing".

Comment: Then this isn't an answer. Do not "answer" off topic questions by guessing. Instead, vote to close the question as "unclear".